# google chrome extension jquery not loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

In the following google chrome extension file why do i cannot use a jquery script inside myscript.js file,Is jquery not loaded inside myscript.js file, what  changes should be done in manifest file to use jquery inside myscript.js

Manifest.json

```
  {
    "manifest_version": 2,

    "name": "One-click Kittens",
    "description": "This extension demonstrates a browser action with kittens.",
    "version": "1.0",
     "background": { "scripts": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js","myscript.js"] },

    "permissions": [
     "tabs", "http://*/*"
    ],
    "browser_action": {
      "default_icon": "icon.png",
      "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }
  }
```

myscript.js

```
 alert($("#extension-command-list").val());    //undefined
 alert($("#extension-command-list").html());   //undefined
 $(document).ready(function() {
    alert("hello world");  //not seen
 });
```

EDIT:

```
"background": { "scripts": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js"] },

 "content_scripts": [
 {
  "matches": ["https://*/*"],
  "js": ["myscript.js"]   or "js": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js","myscript.js"]
 }
],
```

Comment: Actually this should work. *(i just created a new extension with your files and i get the  `hello world` alert)*
There has to be somethign else wrong

Comment: Yes it works ..but when i do any selector and alert when any page laods it says undefined..Any idea why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason you are getting `undefined` is becaus you are not specifying a background page.

So.. the background page Chrome generates, looks just like

```
<html>

    <head></head>

    <body>
        <script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="myscript.js"></script>
    </body>

</html>
```

As you see there isn't any Element which can be selected, thats why your first too `alert`'s return `undefined`.

Anyway, the `alert("hello world")` should be shown too, as the `DOMContentLoaded` *or similar* should be fired any way.

---

Could it be that you want to select Elements of an site you are visiting ?

If so, you should put `myscript.js` in an [Content Script](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) instead of a background page.
There you get access to the DOM of the site.

---

So the question is, what are you up to ?

---

If you actually want to select Elements in your background page, you have to specify one,
Looking at the [background pages](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages.html) site shows you, its as easy as:

> {
>    "name": "My extension",
>    ...
>    "background": {
>    "page": "background.html"
>    },
>    ...
>   }

### Edit:

- "default_popup" : "popup.html"

Refers to a [Browser Actions Popup](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/browserAction.html#popups). A browser Action is used

> [...] to put icons in the main Google Chrome toolbar, to the right of the address bar. In addition to its icon, a browser action can also have a tooltip, a badge, and a popup.

So

> If a browser action has a popup, the popup appears when the user clicks the icon. The popup can contain any HTML contents that you like, and it's automatically sized to fit its contents.
>   To add a popup to your browser action, create an HTML file with the popup's contents. Specify the HTML file in the default_popup field of browser_action in the manifest, or call the setPopup method.

- "background":"{...}"

> A common need for extensions is to have a single long-running script to manage some task or state. Background pages to the rescue.
>   As the architecture overview explains, the background page is an HTML page that runs in the extension process. It exists for the lifetime of your extension, and only one instance of it at a time is active.

Also has a background script **access to all parts of the Chrome Extension's Api.** `chrome.*` *if you have requested the permissions respectively*

---

Now lets  say, you want to for example extend the ContextMenu of chrome with some functionalities.

To do this, you first have create a contextMenuEntry in the background page.
And just like your **background page** has only **one** instance of it running at a time, and that for the **lifetime** of the extension, so should your contextMenuEntry only have **one** instance of it, which gets created when your extension runs and remains for the **lifetime** of your extension.

Now assume you want to display the currently selected text of the **page you are visiting** in one of you Menu Entries.

To do that, you **need** access to the `chrome.contextMenus` API Method but a contentscript is **not** allowed to use this.

To get this to work you need to **pass a message** with the selected text to the **background page** through e.g. `chrome.extension.sendMessage`

In the background page you can then **update** your **existing** contextmenuentry to display the selected text.

*sry i couldn't think of a better example right now*

Comment: yes i want to select element of the site that i am visiting...Please see the EDIT of my manifest file sand let me know if it is fine..

Comment: Now after the edit changes i cannotsee the ready function alert()

Comment: @Rajeev do you want this to match all urls ? if so try changing your match to: `"matches": ["<all_urls>"],` if its not the case, is the page you are visiting using the `https` scheme ?

Comment: My mistake i got it working..But if u can tell me one last thing ..so i would use a html page to show the results only right..

Comment: Glad to hear that, but could you rephrase the last question ? , i don't really get the "so i would use a html page to show the results only right.." part

Comment: so in what context the following are used 1.default_popup": "popup.html" 2. "background": { "scripts": ["jquery-1.9.1.min.js","myscript.js"] }, what are background scripts for?